# how to create autocomplete component in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vue-component

I am facing an issue with my autocomplete component. whenever i type anything into the input field the input is reset.I mean it does not let me type anything.It just keeps getting reset before i could fully type anything.

main.js

```
Vue.component('g-autocomplete', {
  props: ['list','value','title'],
  data() {
    return {
      input: '',
      
    }
  },
  template: `<template>
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input style="font-size: 12pt; height: 36px; width:1800px; " type="text"  v-model="input"  @input="handleInput"/>
     <ul v-if="input" >
      <li v-for="(item, i) in list" :key="i" @click="setInput(item)" >
         <!-- {{ autocompleteData }} -->
          <template v-if="title!='manager'">
          <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{item.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Description:</b>
              {{item.description}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
         <template v-else>
        <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{item.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>First Name:</b>
              {{item.firstName}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Last Name:</b>
              {{item.lastName}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
           </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>`,
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      console.log('inside handleInput')
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value)
    },

    setInput(value) {
      console.log('inside setInput')
      this.input = value
      this.$emit('click', value)
    },

  },
  watch: {
    $props: {
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('new value is'+newValue)
        console.log('old value is'+oldValue)
        console.log('value inside handler'+this.value)
        console.log('list inside handler'+this.list)
        console.log('title inside handler'+this.title)
       this.input=this.value

      }
    }
    // msg(newVal) {
    //     this.msgCopy = newVal;
    // }
}
})
```

i reuse the above component from diffrent vue pages's like this-

```
      <b-field label="Custom Business Unit">
      <g-autocomplete v-on:input="getAsyncDataBusinessUnit" v-on:click="(option) => {updateValue(option.id,'businessUnit')}" :value="this.objectData.businessUnit" :list="dataBusinessUnit" title='businessUnit' >
      </g-autocomplete>
</b-field>
```

my debounce function that is called when something is typed into the input field.

```
getAsyncDataBusinessUnit: debounce(function(name) {
      if (!name.length) {
        this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
        return;
      }
      this.isFetching = true;
      api
        .getSearchData(this.sessionData.key,`/businessunit/?filter={id} LIKE '%25${name}%25' OR {description} LIKE '%25${name}%25'`)
        .then(response => {
          this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
          response.forEach(item => {
            this.dataBusinessUnit.push(item);
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.dataBusinessUnit = [];
          throw error;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isFetching = false;
        });
    }, 500),
```

what could be the issue here ? Also i noticed that the issue doesn't happen  if i comment out the body of the debounce function.So therefore i feel there is something in the debounce function that is causing this.I will try to isolate the problem but i want to understand what exactly is causing this issue. Plz help?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue you met [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4a18cz3h/). But you may want to fix below: 1. remove root element=`<template>` from your template string. 2. uses `this.input=newValue.value` instead of `this.input=this.value`.

Comment: the problem seems to be somewhere in the debounce function.Any modifications(push operation) or reinitialization of the dataBusinessUnit[] array is causing this.I dont understand why though since this debounce function is working perfectly with the previously used buefy's (bulma based) b-autocomplete. Now that i have created my own autocomplete component the loaddash debounce method is misbehaving

Comment: can you try using the loaddash debounce method to fetch the results from an api?